# R integrate() function returns 'non-finite function value'

Tags: r, numerical-methods

I am trying to do k-fold cross validation for Kernel Density Estimation (KDE), which requires me to take the integral of a squared density approximation. This is my current setup

```
# Read in crime data from csv file and select only latitude, longitude columns
crimeData <- read.csv("Crimes-Map.csv")
crimeData <- crimeData[, 15:16]
# Remove NAs from the data
cleanData <- crimeData[complete.cases(crimeData), ]
lat <- cleanData[[1]]
lon <- cleanData[[2]]

## Extra code to split my data into k sets ##

hSeq <- seq(0.001, 0.05, by=0.001)
JHLat <- numeric(length(hSeq))
for (i in 1:length(hSeq)) {
  h <- hSeq[i]

  ## Lots of code that's running fine ##

  # Get density estimate for full data to compute J(h)
  latDensity <- density(lat, bw = h)
  latDensFunc <- approxfun(latDensity)
  latSq <- function(x) latDensFunc(x)^2
  # Get support of this density so we integrate over the right region
  loLat <- min(latDensity$x)
  hiLat <- max(latDensity$x)
  JHLat[i] <- integrate(latSq, lower = loLat, upper = hiLat)$value # + other term coming from rest of code
}
```

Everything works fine up to the integrate function, where I get the following error:

> Error in integrate(lonSq, lower = loLon, upper = hiLon) : 
>     non-finite function value

I've plotted latSq and also checked that there are no infinite or NaN's over the support of the density using the following commands

```
xs <- seq(loLat, hiLat, by = 1e-4)
any(is.infinte(latSq(xs))
any(is.nan(latSq(xs))
```

And both return false. For reference, loLat is 36.61645 and hiLat is 42.02557. I know that latDensity has a maximum value of 29.979 so latSq should have a max value of 898.7404 which I'm pretty sure isn't big enough to cause an issue. So I'm very confused as to what is happening and how I can fix it - any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be checking interpolated values of your function, not the integration domain. One of the values must be `NaN`, and I can't provide more information because there is no data.

I can only guess what is going on. Since you are using `approxfux`, the interpolated function (`latDensFunc`) returns `NaN` for one of the points. This is what leads to `NaN`s in `lonSq`.

Comment: I was an idiot, it was all a simple typo. Thanks for helping me find it